# MySQL Cluster node utf8

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster, encoding

I have configured MySQL Cluster (5.6) with two data nodes and managment node.
Problem is that I cannot put special chars - looks like encoding is not set to utf8/utf16.

I logged into each node and set server encoding, database encding etc. to UTF8, but this not helped (it helped on standard MySQL server). Tables are also created with utf8.

Is there any other settings (maybe on managment node?) that should I set up to utf8 (or utf16)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show us what you did to (1) use utf8 in the client(s), (2) how you established the charset from client to server, and (3) `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

If you left out any one of those, that that is likely to be the problem.

Do not use utf16, only use utf8.  (Unless you have some good argument to the contrary.)

If you have `INSERTed` some data, let's see `SELECT col, HEX(col)...` to see if it was garbled on the way in.